# How to print report

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I want to print a *JR* report.

I am trying this code

```java
JasperPrint jp = new JasperFillManager().fillReport("billReport", billId, 
    "jdbc:mysql://localhost/kpc_hospital");  
JasperPrintManager.printReport(jp, true)
```

but this code is not working.

Comment: In what way is it not working?

Comment: I want to print directly jesper report without showing print dialog but this code not working

Comment: @MubashirHassan if you will use printReport(print,false), no print dialog will appear.

Comment: I'm not using this method

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are different methods, that you can use to print you Jasper Report directly instead of showing Print Dialog.

Simplest way is:

```
    Connection con;
    String url="jdbc:mysql://localhost/mydb";
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
    con=(Connection) DriverManager.getConnection(url,"root","");
    JasperReport jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(fileName);
    JasperPrint print = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, parameter, con);
    print.setPageHeight(100);
    print.setPageWidth(80);
    print.setOrientation(jasperReport.getOrientationValue().LANDSCAPE);
    JasperPrintManager.printReport(print,false);
```

You can also use this:

```
    PrinterJob job = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
    int selectedService = 0;
    selectedService = 0;
    PrintRequestAttributeSet printRequestAttributeSet = new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet();
    printRequestAttributeSet.add(OrientationRequested.PORTRAIT);
    printRequestAttributeSet.add(MediaSizeName.ISO_A0); 
    MediaSizeName mediaSizeName = MediaSize.findMedia(64,25,MediaPrintableArea.MM);
    printRequestAttributeSet.add(mediaSizeName);
    printRequestAttributeSet.add(new Copies(1));
    JRPrintServiceExporter exporter;
    exporter = new JRPrintServiceExporter();
    exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT, jasper_print);
    exporter.setParameter(JRPrintServiceExporterParameter.PRINT_REQUEST_ATTRIBUTE_SET, printRequestAttributeSet);
    exporter.setParameter(JRPrintServiceExporterParameter.DISPLAY_PAGE_DIALOG, Boolean.FALSE);
    exporter.setParameter(JRPrintServiceExporterParameter.DISPLAY_PRINT_DIALOG, Boolean.TRUE);
    exporter.exportReport();
    job.print(printRequestAttributeSet);
```

Comment: The above code works fine in local host, but when i host the application, the print dialog never shown and does not add the report to printer queue

Comment: @Senthil : check this --- String url="jdbc:mysql://localhost/mydb";

Comment: Hi Imran. Thanks, But i am not connecting with db using connection. I am passing List and showing the Jasper Report. I mean the second part in the above  works fine locally, but when i host the application in server and launch the application in the browser and try the same one, it never shown the printer dialog